# Setting date format in gsheet through python api using sheet.insert_row()

Tags: python, json, google-api-python-client, pygsheets

I have a list of data let say

```
record = ['Tuesday','2018-08-29']
```

and I try to send it to google sheet through

```
sheet.insert_row(record,index)
```

and I am successfully receiving it on my gsheet but the issue is, that on the gsheet I am getting a date as a string and I can not apply any formula on it. I try to convert the string to date format

```
import datetime


record[1] = datetime.datetime.strptime(record[1], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

but then on using insert_row is giving me error that

```
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: hey @Muhammad Ahmad did you ever find out how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Google Sheets API Docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts), you must format your date as a float of days since the Google Sheets epoch of December 30, 1899.

For instance, in my code I am working with `Pandas` timestamps but you can work with another timestamp datatype as you please:

```
time = (pd.to_datetime(time) - pd.datetime(1899, 12, 30)) / pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D')
```

Upon passing this through to API into a Google sheet with the column formatted properly, you will get a google datetime type.